# What does "Bad gRPC response. HTTP status code: 401" mean as response in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-booking

I try to use the Microsoft Graph API to access appointments in Microsoft Bookings because I want to be able to automatically delete appointments. I have an access token, I got it using msal for Python. This way worked also to access the IMAP mailbox of my organization. I also got the right permission:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingbusiness-list-appointments?view=graph-rest-1.0 says I need BookingsAppointment.ReadWrite.All and I have that one, see image.
[Permissions screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8SN1.png).

When running the following code:

```
load_dotenv()

def get_access_token():
    tenant_id = os.getenv("TENANT_ID")
    authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'
    clientID = os.getenv("CLIENT_ID_DELETE_BOOKINGS")
    clientSecret = os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET_DELETE_BOOKINGS")
    scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(clientID, authority=authority, 
          client_credential = clientSecret)
    access_token = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
    return access_token

access_token = get_access_token()
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
    # "Content-type": "application/json"
    # "Host": "graph.microsoftonline.com"
}
id_user = #redacted - here is the id in the form of 'appointmenttype@company.nl'
url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/solutions/bookingBusinesses/{id_user}/appointments"

response = requests.request("GET", url=url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

I get the following response:

```
{"error":{"code":"UnknownError","message":"{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Bad gRPC response. HTTP status code: 401\",\"code\":\"Unauthorized\"}}","innerError":{"date":"2023-04-28T10:48:01","request-id":"ab1a2ce6-e8ce-4ad1-8950-02d4183a0fab","client-request-id":"ab1a2ce6-e8ce-4ad1-8950-02d4183a0fab"}}}
```

Especially the `Bad gRPC response` is something that I cannot find anywhere on the internet except for some .NET fora.

I checked and dubble checked the credentials from my app in Azure, I tried different headers such as `"Host": "graph.microsoftonline.com"`. I expect a normal result as decribed in the Graph documentation, but I keep getting the `bad gRPC` response.

Comment: Could you please try adding the other permissions as well and see of that works:Bookings.Read.All,  Bookings.ReadWrite.All, Bookings.Manage.All

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue myself, but solved it by adding API permission **Bookings.Read.All** as suggested by 
[Mehtab Siddique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17982436/mehtab-siddique).